# How to extract a string from a point to another?

Tags: python, string, function, extract

is there a way to extract a text from a string, by searching from a point until another one?

For example I have the following string:

```
string = {"sn":"Arsenal To Win","mn":"Match Result","ewc":"1/1 1","cid":9281870353,"prt":"CP","ewf":"1.0","epr":"2.12","prices":{"0":"28/25","1":"2.12","2":"+112","3":"1.12","4":"-0.893","5":"1.12"}}
```

and what i would like to extract is the first value 2.12, between "epr" and "prices"

I tried many options, for example:
 `line.startswith("epr")` but It doesn't work well, so the most simple what i tried, without write too much line of code is:

```
test = string[103:108]
print test
```

The problem is it's not dynamic, is there a dynamic way to do it?

Thanks a lot for your help!!!!

Comment: Looks like what you have is not a string but a dictionary

Comment: That's not a string.... it's an object called dictionary... what's your really need?

Comment: I'm really sorry, I'm new in Python and I didn't know it was a json... I solved it in this way: j = json.loads(string)['epr']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your object is not a string, but a dictionary. The `2.12` is not “between” the `'epr'` and the `'prices'`; it is bound to the `'epr'` only, and since dictionaries are unordered, it is not logically “followed” by `'prices'` anyway. If you want to access the `2.12`, that’s simply

```
string['epr']
```